help on Automation SQL query time out
looking for suggestions on how to optimize a query for updating a table with 2M records from a table that has 500k records.
I have a daily automation that has an sql step query that is used to update a table. but when that table now has 1.9M records, the query is now timing out. I tried a workaround query from chatgpt and a staging query, it worked for a day, then it timed out again the next day.
Original query:
Data Extension and action:
UPDATE Contacts_ChangeLog
SELECT 
    NEWID() AS GUID,
    de.subscriber_key,
    de.first_name,
    de.last_name,
    de.phone,
    de.postcode,
    de.state,
    de.dob,
    de.email,
    de.country,
    de.pref_dhp_opted_in_email,
    de.pref_dhp_opted_in_sms,
    de.pref_gp_opted_in_email,
    de.pref_gp_opted_in_sms,
    de.gr_membership_id,
    de.gr_membership_start_date,
    de.pref_dhp_sms_last_updated_date,
    de.pref_gp_sms_last_updated_date,
    de.sent_sms_api,
    de.pref_last_updated_date
FROM ContactsDE de
LEFT JOIN Contacts_ChangeLog c1 
ON de.subscriber_key = c1.subscriber_key
WHERE c1.subscriber_key IS NULL

this workaround query from chatgpt worked only once:
SELECT 
    NEWID() AS GUID,
    de.subscriber_key,
    de.first_name,
    de.last_name,
    de.phone,
    de.postcode,
    de.state,
    de.dob,
    de.email,
    de.country,
    de.pref_dhp_opted_in_email,
    de.pref_dhp_opted_in_sms,
    de.pref_gp_opted_in_email,
    de.pref_gp_opted_in_sms,
    de.gr_membership_id,
    de.gr_membership_start_date,
    de.pref_dhp_sms_last_updated_date,
    de.pref_gp_sms_last_updated_date,
    de.sent_sms_api,
    de.pref_last_updated_date
FROM ContactsDE de
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Contacts_ChangeLog c1
    WHERE de.subscriber_key = c1.subscriber_key
)

I tried also tried a staging approach, i'm not sure if i've done it correctly. this also time out for the Update step of the automation
Step1: overwrite StagingSegment_Contacts_ChangeLog_SQLDE
    SELECT
    de.subscriber_key,
    c1.subscriber_key as subscriberkeynullcheck,
    de.first_name,
    de.last_name,
    de.phone,
    de.postcode,
    de.state,
    de.dob,
    de.email,
    de.country,
    de.pref_dhp_opted_in_email,
    de.pref_dhp_opted_in_sms,
    de.pref_gp_opted_in_email,
    de.pref_gp_opted_in_sms,
    de.gr_membership_id,
    de.gr_membership_start_date,
    de.pref_dhp_sms_last_updated_date,
    de.pref_gp_sms_last_updated_date,
    de.sent_sms_api,
    de.pref_last_updated_date
FROM Contacts_DE de
LEFT JOIN TestContacts_ChangeLog_SQLDE c1 
ON de.subscriber_key = c1.subscriber_key

Step 2: overwrite     StagingSegment2_Contacts_ChangeLog_SQLDE
SELECT *
FROM StagingSegment_Contacts_ChangeLog_SQLDE
where subscriberkeynullcheck IS NULL

Step 3: (timed out)
UPDATE TestContacts_ChangeLog_SQLDE
(this DE currently has 1.9M records)
    SELECT 
    NEWID() AS GUID,
    de.subscriber_key,
    de.first_name,
    de.last_name,
    de.phone,
    de.postcode,
    de.state,
    de.dob,
    de.email,
    de.country,
    de.pref_dhp_opted_in_email,
    de.pref_dhp_opted_in_sms,
    de.pref_gp_opted_in_email,
    de.pref_gp_opted_in_sms,
    de.gr_membership_id,
    de.gr_membership_start_date,
    de.pref_dhp_sms_last_updated_date,
    de.pref_gp_sms_last_updated_date,
    de.sent_sms_api,
    de.pref_last_updated_date
FROM StagingSegment_Contacts_ChangeLog_SQLDE de
INNER JOIN StagingSegment2_Contacts_ChangeLog_SQLDE c1
ON de.subscriber_key = c1.subscriber_key
WHERE c1.subscriberkeynullcheck IS NULL

when i ran this query above in the query studio, it has 497k records, but it is timing out when it is used to update the DE with a 2M records

You'll have to split your query into multiple queries.  My preferred method is to utilize the hidden _customObjectKey identity value and the modulo (%) operator.

NOTE: I don't recommend select * queries, but only used them to illustrate the method.  They will work in SFMC, but it's a best practice to specify all columns as you did in your example.

SELECT 
  NEWID() AS GUID
, c.*
FROM ContactsDE as c
WHERE 
de._customObjectKey % 5 = 0
and NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT top 1 cl.subscriber_key
    FROM Contacts_ChangeLog as cl
    WHERE cl.subscriber_key = c.subscriber_key
)

SELECT 
  NEWID() AS GUID
, c.*
FROM ContactsDE as c
WHERE 
de._customObjectKey % 5 = 1
and NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT top 1 cl.subscriber_key
    FROM Contacts_ChangeLog as cl
    WHERE cl.subscriber_key = c.subscriber_key
)

SELECT 
  NEWID() AS GUID
, c.*
FROM ContactsDE as c
WHERE 
de._customObjectKey % 5 = 2
and NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT top 1 cl.subscriber_key
    FROM Contacts_ChangeLog as cl
    WHERE cl.subscriber_key = c.subscriber_key
)

SELECT 
  NEWID() AS GUID
, c.*
FROM ContactsDE as c
WHERE 
de._customObjectKey % 5 = 3
and NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT top 1 cl.subscriber_key
    FROM Contacts_ChangeLog as cl
    WHERE cl.subscriber_key = c.subscriber_key
)

SELECT 
  NEWID() AS GUID
, c.*
FROM ContactsDE as c
WHERE 
de._customObjectKey % 5 = 4
and NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT top 1 cl.subscriber_key
    FROM Contacts_ChangeLog as cl
    WHERE cl.subscriber_key = c.subscriber_key
)



The numbers you cite aren't exactly huge for SFMC standards, so the bottleneck should not be DE size alone;

The chatGPT solution (WHERE NOT EXISTS instead of LEFT JOIN WHERE target key IS NULL) should be more performant and should do the job.


So: Little optimization potential in the SQL.
->
Which leaves the factor of the DEs, more precisely: Primary Keys.  Primary Keys as a "byproduct" get indexed. Working with indexed fields speeds database operations up significantly. (Which is likely also why SFMC's UI only allows record search using Primary Keys, without it it's just too slow / resource intensive.)
So: verify that you JOIN ON fields that are Primary Keys (subscriber_key) in both DEs. This should have rather impressive positive impact on execution time.
If I understand your scenario correctly you would want to make both GUID &
subscriber_key Primary Keys in your target DE so that multiple entries per subscriberKey can be entered.

It would be faster and more efficent to append rathar then update.
First create a backup of your "Contacts_ChangeLog" for security
Use the following steps:

Establish the Update rows and the append rows from the new file onto a new DE
Delete the update rows from the final DE (using SSJS)
append The file created on step 1 onto the final DE.

Step 1)
Identify Deltas and Update Rows (this will give you all 500K formatted in the way you require in the "Contacts_ChangeLog" DE), instert these into a DE (i will call "Contacts_ChangeLog_Staging")  :
SELECT 
NEWID() AS GUID
,   A.*
,   0       AS 'IS_NEW'
FROM [ContactsDE] A
LEFT JOIN [Contacts_ChangeLog] AS B WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.[subscriber_key] = B.[subscriber_key]
WHERE B.[subscriber_key] IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT
    NEWID() AS GUID
,       A.*
,       1       AS 'IS_NEW'
FROM [ContactsDE] A
LEFT JOIN [Contacts_ChangeLog] AS B WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.[subscriber_key ] = B.[subscriber_key]
WHERE B.[subscriber_key] IS NULL

Step 2)
Create SSJS to delete the rows requiring updating:
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var deleteDE = DataExtension.Init(‘**EXTERNALKEY OF THE "Contacts_ChangeLog_Staging" DE**’);
var data = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows("Contacts_ChangeLog_Staging", 9999999,"IS_NEW ASC", "IS_NEW", "0");
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { 
var subKey = data[i].NAME OF PRIMARY KEY IN DELTAS DE;
var rowDelete = Platform.Function.DeleteData(‘Contacts_ChangeLog',['subscriber_key'],[subKey]);
};
</script>



once deleted do a simple query and set that to append onto the "Contacts_ChangeLog" DE.

SELECT
*
FROM [Contacts_ChangeLog_Staging]

This process will cut your runtime down significantly and is scalable when your numbers are significantly larger.
